# HP SE1220 refuses to boot

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, boot

I got a replacement system board for my DL180 G6 ([old thread here](https://serverfault.com/questions/790923/hp-proliant-dl180-g6-refuses-to-boot)) which is almost identical apart from the management console iLO 2 which was separate in my old board. The new one has far more status LEDs too. However, all old forum threads link to service manuals which are no longer available/dead links, so I can't tell which LEDs means what.

Symptoms:

- When power is first applied, LED 5 through 8 cycles though, then goes black. After that, LED 1 and 2 starts flashing slowly.
- If I press the power button, the front LED turns red, all diagnostic LEDs turn black, the fans spin for about a second at low power and both red LEDs close to each processor turns red for a brief moment, then nothing and the fans stop turning.
- iOL 2 is working and I can log in, but this does not diagnose anything if the system is not running.

I have tried the following:

- Reseated the CPU. Nothing.
- Pulled RAM down to just one or two sticks. Nothing. One stick is not supported but it gives the same behavior.
- Pulled accessory cards, the whole raiser card. Nothing.
- Tried different fan connectors, they all spin the fans. Won't boot.
- Replaced the CPU to a faster one. The initial LED 5-8 sequence is slightly different as is the overlap in time between LED1-2, but the overall symptom is identical.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I measured the +5V and it measures 0.74 V, or just about exactly one diode drop. Both power supplies in both slots so it can only be the power backplane or the 5V rail failed on both power supplies in the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Got a new backplane. Server is up and running again.

Note to anyone who have only partial functionality, especially with fans running at partial or full speed and server not booting - measure the 5 V rail.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the series of steps you can try to get this system to POST.

If you have physical access to the server, you can try this sequence:

> - Remove the power supply units and swap them.

Test to see if the system will boot...

If that doesn't work:

> - Remove all power supplies from the chassis
> - Locate the *System Maintenance Switch* on the motherboard - It's a set of 10 DIP switches.
> - Turn switch #6 switch on.
> - Insert all power supply units.
> - Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
> - Power the server off.
> - Remove all power supplies.
> - Return DIP switch #6 to off (original) position.
> - Reinsert the power supplies.
> - Power the server on.

Test to see if the system will boot...

If that doesn't work:

> - Remove all power supplies from the chassis
> - Turn DIP switches #1, 5 and 6 switch on.
> - Insert all power supply units.
> - Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
> - Power the server off.
> - Remove all power supplies.
> - Return DIP switches #1, 5 and 6 to off (original) position.
> - Reinsert the power supplies.
> - Power the server on.

Test to see if the system will boot...

Also see: [HP ProLiant DL380 G7 servers will not POST](https://serverfault.com/questions/558019/hp-proliant-dl380-g7-servers-will-not-post/558023#558023)

Comment: I have eight DIP switches on it. I found references to the 10 DIP switches in other manuals and just flicked them all to on in order to bypass the iLO password and that worked. I tried a few one by one but not those particual combos. I'll fire it up tomorrow and see if anything helps. In general, resetting the configuraion should be good because iLO still reports the last configuration and does not respond to memory nor CPU changes.

Comment: Found it! The power backplane is bad. I took it apart and it seems to be just two TPS0057 in parallel inside it, one from each power supply +12V and if one goes to short, your entire 5 V is screwed.

Comment: Very good for you!

Comment: Well, at least now I have a spare system board, RAM and CPU. They didn't match however so I suppose I need to get an identical CPU before I can use the extra RAM too. Anywho, I'm curious about this redundant power supply since it's my job designing them. It's also not a space shuttle nor satellite but in the space industry, this is THE fault case to handle. No single short anywhere should bring down anything. If both +5 and both +12 are tied together, it's a huge setback in terms of redundancy. I have a new backplane on the way in. I'll post an update.